# Entity Framework One To One Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, left-join, entity-relationship

I've been stuck in creating what should be a very simple EF Relationship.

I want a Company property to have a navigation property to a Client. This will be an optional relationship, meaning that a Company may not have a Client property.

The Company table has a PK called "CompanyId" and the Client table has a PK called "ClientId"

On the Client Model we have:

```
[ForeignKey("ClientId")]
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

On the Company we have:

```
[ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

In the Client Map, I have:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Company)
    .WithOptional(x => x.Client)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I've tried at least 20 variations, by trying to create the relationship on either the client or company man.

On my controller, this is the query:

```
    var query = (from c in service.GetCompanies()
                join t in service.GetCompanyCategories() on c.CompanyId equals t.CompanyId
                join o in service.GetClients() on c.CompanyId equals o.ClientId
                into ctos
                from cto in ctos.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby c.CompanyName
                where c.CompanyIsActive == true && t.CategoryId == categoryId
                select c)
            .ToList();
```

The page loads, with no EF errors (unlike many variations I've tried before), but yet on the cshtml page, the c.Client is null despite it having the relationship in the database.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should be very simple... But EF has limited `one-to-one` support. What you want is simply not possible - see [Associations in EF Code First: Part 5 – One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations).

Comment: We're in a good spot to change the schema of the database as we're redesigning & restructuring the db since it was all developed in the mid 90s. What do you think the best option would be? It would be great if the Client could navigate to the Company and the Company could navigate to the Client. Any thoughts? (And thanks for confirming that I was trying to do the impossible!)

Comment: You could try the second EF6 supported option [Associations in EF Code First: Part 3 – Shared Primary Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations), which supports bidirectional navigation.

Comment: On the Client table I added a CompanyId column, which is nullable, but as a relationship from that column to the table Company.CompanyId. I changed the linq query above so that the join is c.CompanyId = c.CompanyId. However, now I get the error "Invalid column name 'Client_ClientId'."